# Maximum number of subarrays having equal sum

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, prefix

I was asked this question in one of my interview. Given an array of integers (**with both positive and negative values**) we need to find the **maximum number of disjoint subarrays having equal sum**.

**Example :**

Input : [1, 2, 3]
Output : 2 {since we have at most 2 subarrays with sum = 3 i.e. [1, 2],[3]}

Input: [2 2 2 -2]
Output : 2 {two subarrays each with sum = 2 i.e. [2],[2, 2, -2]}

**My Approach**

First approach that came to my mind was to find the prefix sum array and then taking each element (prefix[i]) as target finding the number of subarrays with sum = prefix[i] .

But this failed in the case of negative numbers. How to handle the negative cases?

**EDIT** Complete array must be covered with these subarrays. That is why in example 2 we get **2** as output and not 3 ([2],[2],[2]).

Comment: when you partition the array to equal sum sub arrays, can there be some remainder(s) of elements that you don't include in the partitions (at the beginning or start of the sub arrays of course)

Comment: Any constraints on the range of `array[i]`?

Comment: Do I assume that the disjoint arrays - in union - have to span the *entire* array? Otherwise I think the result of example 2) would be `3` by splitting `[[2], [2], [2], -2]` i. e. 3 disjoint arrays `[2]` and `-2` not being included in any array.

Comment: @Reizo I have updated the question. We need to cover the entire array with those subarrays.

Answer (score 4):

**First, assuming that they can be non-consecutive elements**

Probably there is not efficient algorithm (if so, P=NP), then, simply check all possible combinations (partitions).

If `partitions` is a function returning all partitions given a set, then your problem is solved with:

```
static Optional<List<List<Integer>>> maximumSubarraysEqSum(List<Integer> xs) {
  return
    // all indexes partitions
    partitions(IntStream.range(0, xs.size()).mapToObj(x -> x).collect(toList()))
    // with all groups with same sum
    .stream().filter(zs -> zs.stream().mapToInt(ys -> ys.stream().mapToInt(xs::get).sum()).distinct().count() == 1L)
    // sorting by size desc
    .sorted((zs, ys) -> Integer.compare(ys.size(), zs.size()))
    // first (or all with same size if you want, ...)
    .findFirst()
    // map indexes to values
    .map(zs -> zs.stream().map(ys -> ys.stream().map(xs::get).collect(toList())).collect(toList()));
}
```

running

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("    " + maximumSubarraysEqSum(List.of(1, 2, 3)));
    System.out.println("    " + maximumSubarraysEqSum(List.of(2, 2, 2, -2)));
    System.out.println("    " + maximumSubarraysEqSum(List.of(3, 4)));
}
```

the output is

```
Optional[[[1, 2], [3]]]
Optional[[[2, 2, -2], [2]]]
Optional[[[3, 4]]]
```

**Second, assuming they must be consecutive elements**

The first subarray set what sum is possible, then for every possible *"first sum"* we check the number of groups

```
static int maxSubarrayEqSum(List<Integer> xs) {
    // possible sizes for the first subarray
    return IntStream.range(1, xs.size() + 1)
            // with that sum count (if exists) how many subarrays match
            .map(sz -> countMaxSubArrayEqSum(0, xs, xs.stream().limit(sz).mapToInt(x -> x).sum()))
            // get the maximum number
            .max()
            .getAsInt();
}
```

counting the maximum subarrays is get the first possible sum

```
static int countMaxSubArrayEqSum(int from, List<Integer> xs, int sz) {
    int acc = 0;
    for(int i = from; i < xs.size(); i++) {
        acc += xs.get(i);
        if(acc == sz) {
            if(i == xs.size() - 1)
                return 1;
            int count = countMaxSubArrayEqSum(i + 1, xs, sz);
            if(count > 0)
                return count + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Optimal solution for consecutive sequences O(n^2)**

Instead backtracking, we can get the `maxSplit` value (maximum of groups) checking if `xs` can be divided by `|xs|`, `|xs|-1`, `|xs|-2`, ..., `1` groups.

```
static int maxSplit(int [] xs) {

    // sum all
    int S = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < xs.length; i++)
        S += xs[i];

    // try every possible number of groups
    for(int i = xs.length; i > 1; i--)
        if(S % i == 0 && maxSplitFit(xs, i, S / i))
            return i;

    return 1;
}
```

`xs` can be divided into `k` groups if we can use a voracious strategy

```
static boolean maxSplitFit(int [] xs, int k, int s) {

    int groupsCount = 1;
    int acc = 0;

    // look for (not final) groups summing S/k
    int i = 0;
    while(i < xs.length - 1 && groupsCount < k) {
        acc += xs[i];
        if ((s == 0 && acc == 0) // divide by 0
         || (s != 0 && s * groupsCount == acc)) // S/k
            groupsCount++;
        i++;
    }

    // if there are not enough groups then it is not possible
    if(groupsCount != k)
        return false;

    // the last group must contains all remaining elements
    while(i < xs.length)
        acc += xs[i++];

    // S/k for every group
    return s * k == acc;
}
```

**Aside**

A possible function to get all partitions could be

```
static <T> List<List<List<T>>> partitions(List<T> set) {
    // last element
    T element = set.get(set.size() - 1);

    if (set.size() == 1)
        return singletonList(singletonList(singletonList(element)));

    List<List<List<T>>> current = new ArrayList<>();

    // it could be in any of previous groups or in a new one

    // add on every previous
    for (List<List<T>> p : partitions(set.subList(0, set.size() - 1))) {
        // every candidate group to place
        for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
            List<List<T>> b = new ArrayList<>(p);
            b.add(i, new ArrayList<>(b.remove(i)));
            b.get(i).add(element);
            current.add(b);
        }
        // add singleton
        List<List<T>> b = new ArrayList<>(p);
        b.add(singletonList(element));
        current.add(b);
    }

    return current;
}
```

Comment: In my experience, 'subarray' almost always refers to *contiguous* subarrays, which makes sense with OP's examples. If the problem were about subsets, it would be much harder as you point out, but since OP tried using prefix sums, it seems safe to assume they meant contiguous arrays (so there is a polynomial solution).

Comment: @kcsquared then the solution is trivial

Comment: @kcsquared (I have updated the answer with solutions to the two possible interpretations)

Comment: I don't know if it's totally trivial, but it seems slightly more likely than an interviewer asking about an uncommon variant of an NP-hard problem. OP hasn't specified whether the entire array must be partitioned; it seems like your solution assumes that it does. Is your second solution `O(n)`?

Comment: @kcsquared no, the trivial solution is exponential, `O(n)` is a requirement? (also, since they are considered negative numbers, it is not clear to me that there is a solution in P)

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure, but that solution (for the entire array partition case) is about as complex as your current one. If OP meant that the subarrays don't need to span the entire array, then the question becomes a bit harder-- it's hard to see how to solve it in better than quadratic time.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** OP has clarified that the entire array must be partitioned into complete subarrays. As such, the first half of this post constitutes a full answer, but the second half may still be useful as a soltuion to a generalization of this question.

---

If we're using the whole array, the problem can be solved in `O(n)` time, which is optimal. We get to use the fact that splitting `A` into `k` subarrays means all subarrays will have a sum of `sum(A)/k`. After computing the array sum, we can solve the problem in a single pass through the array, using just prefix sums and a hashmap.

If we're not using the whole array, the problem is harder. There's an `O(n^2)` solution where you compute all subarray sums, sort equal-sum subarrays by right endpoint, and use greedy interval scheduling. I have no idea if this is optimal, but I'm interested to see if there's a better solution.

---

**Full array partition case**

The precise problem definition here is to find the length of the longest sequence of points `[x_0, x_1, ... x_m]` such that `0 <= x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_m < length(A)` such that `sum(A[0:x_0]) == sum(A[x_0:x_1]) == ... == sum(A[x_m:length(A)])`.

Suppose we've computed the sum of the array to be `S`. Then, we can split `A` into `k` parts of equal sum if and only if (`k` divides `S` *and* if we see `S/k, 2S/k, ... , kS/k` as a subsequence of the prefix sums of `A`). One easy way to do that is to keep a running sum: if our running sum `r` divides `S`, then save `2S/r` in a hashmap as a 'sum we're searching for'. If our current sum is one we've been searching for, save the next number from that subsequence as a 'sum we're searching for', unless we've reached the end of that sequence.

For example, say that `S` is `32`. Then, `A` can be partitioned into `8` equal sum subarrays if and only if `4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28` appears as a subsequence of the prefix sums of `A` (`32` will always be present at the end). So as soon as we see `4` as a prefix sum, we check that it divides `S`, and then save `8` to our search set for prefix sums. We also keep a helper dictionary, mapping `8` to `4`, so that after finding `8` as a prefix sum, we know that `8+4` is the next prefix sum to look for.

Python code:

```py
def best_full_partition(nums: List[int]) -> int:
    """Given a list of integers (positive or negative) 'nums',
    return the maximum number of disjoint equal sum subarrays we can
    partition nums into (using all elements)"""

    total = sum(nums)

    # Special case where total sum is 0
    if total == 0:
        # Count the number of times 0 is a partial sum
        answer = 0
        current_sum = 0
        for x in nums:
            current_sum += x
            if current_sum == 0:
                answer += 1
        return answer

    best_found = 1

    # Prefix sums we're trying to find; all share common factor with total
    looking_for = set()

    """ Map from prefix sums to the common factor/original prefix sum.
        There may be several: e.g. total/6 and total/3 may be targets
        of 2*total/3. """
    looking_to_original_sums = collections.defaultdict(set)

    current_sum = 0

    for x in nums:
        current_sum += x
        if current_sum == 0:
            continue

        if current_sum in looking_for:
            for original_sum in looking_to_original_sums[current_sum]:
                new_target = current_sum + original_sum

                # If we've found all matches in this chain
                if new_target == total:
                    best_found = max(best_found, total // original_sum)
                    continue

                looking_for.add(new_target)
                looking_to_original_sums[new_target].add(original_sum)

            looking_to_original_sums.pop(current_sum)
            looking_for.discard(current_sum)

        # Check if current sum is a divisor of full array sum
        if total % current_sum == 0:
            # If this splits array in half by sum, we've reached its end
            if 2 * current_sum == total:
                best_found = max(best_found, 2)
            else:
                # Add the next multiple of this sum to our search set
                looking_for.add(2 * current_sum)
                looking_to_original_sums[2 * current_sum].add(current_sum)

    return best_found
```

This takes `O(n)` time, which is optimal, and `O(n)` space.

---

**Partial array partition**

This case is harder, because there's fewer conditions on what the valid subarray sums can be. The trick is to just compute the sum of all subarrays. We make a hashmap, mapping each sum to the index bounds of its subarray, so `sum(A[L, L+1, ... R])` maps to `[L, R]`. Since there are duplicates, we keep a list of all intervals which produced that sum, and we generate that list to be sorted by the right endpoint.

Now, we can use [earliest deadline first scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling), aka greedy scheduling, to find the maximum number of intervals we can take from that list without overlap. Both steps take quadratic time. It may be possible to improve this, but I have no ideas for how to do so.

Python code:

```py
def best_partial_partition(nums: List[int]) -> int:
    """Given a list of integers (positive or negative) 'nums',
    return the maximum number of disjoint equal sum subarrays we can
    create from nums (using all elements is not required)"""

    n = len(nums)

    best_found = 1

    # For each subarray sum, stores a list of all subarrays with that sum
    # Sorted by right endpoint, both ends inclusive
    sum_to_intervals = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for right_end in range(n):
        curr_sum = 0
        for left_end in reversed(range(right_end+1)):
            curr_sum += nums[left_end]
            sum_to_intervals[curr_sum].append([left_end, right_end])

    # Use greedy interval scheduling to get most intervals

    for interval_list in sum_to_intervals.values():
        # Can skip if we know no improvement is possible here
        if len(interval_list) <= best_found:
            continue

        curr_len = 0
        curr_right_end = -1
        for left, right in interval_list:
            if left > curr_right_end:
                curr_len += 1
                curr_right_end = right

        best_found = max(best_found, curr_len)

    return best_found
```

This runs in `O(n^2)` time.

**Edit**: Fixed a bug in full partition solver when the array sum was 0; thanks to @josejuan for pointing this out. This case needs to be treated separately to avoid dividing by zero.

Comment: _"Full array partition"_ is basically the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem where we add to your input the SSP input plus one more value `S=half the sum of all inputs`. Your algorithm if works will return three sets, the two partitions and S. Are you sure take `O(n)` and works?

Comment: @josejuan I'm not sure about that; my interpretation of OP's question is that it asked about subarrays, rather than subsets. Admittedly, they haven't posted in a while to clear this up, but I've almost never seen 'subarrays' refer to non-contiguous groups. I'd also be very surprised if multiway number partitioning (another NP-hard problem, closer to what you're describing) was asked about during an interview-- you can't even use any meet-in-the-middle tricks like subset-sum, so it seems brutally hard and also pointless to be an interview question.

Comment: What I am saying, is that if your algorithm works, P=NP. With this example I would say that it does not work (it returns 1 but it is 5) `[-3, 1, 2], [1, -1], [-2, 2], [-2, 2], [1, 1, -2]`.

Comment: @josejuan That's a very good catch; I mishandled the case where the full sum is zero. It's fixable (and still `O(n)`), thanks for finding that. Now that OP clarified and edited the post, the interpretation from the 'full array partition' case is actually what they were asking for, which is different from the subset sum problem.

Comment: fail with `[-3, 1], [-2], [-3, 1], [2, -2, -2], [-2]` (you can use my solution to check yours instead me using yours to check you? ;)

Comment: @josejuan Thanks for all the testing and help. That's very strange; I've tested the example `[-3, 1, -2, -3, 1, 2, -2, -2, -2]` with every version of the code that's been posted, and they all return 5. The only problem I'm aware of is in the first version of the code when the full array sum was zero, and I've since tested the updated code against a brute force solution as well. Just to double check, are you using Python version 3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241800/discussion-between-josejuan-and-kcsquared).

Comment: I've inspected your solution for some time and I am not yet entirely confident it's actually `O(n)`. however I was not able to disprove it either. You might add some explanation to convince me ;) Regardless, this certainly is a clever solution with some clever thoughts!

Comment: yup, @Reizo is right, since the `for interval_list` can grow up to `n`

Comment: @josejuan I think you must've mixed tings up; there is no `interval_list` in the `O(n)`-code.

Comment: mmm sorry `for original_sum` xD

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I assume the whole array needs to be covered with sub-arrays.</sub>

After thinking about it for some time I am pretty confident, that the following `O(n^2)` algorithm should be valid:

```
public static int maxSplitCount(int[] a) {

    int res = 0; // highest sub-array count found so far

    int sum = 0; // sum within each sub-array
    for (int i = 0; i != a.length; ++i) { // iterate over any possible front sub-array...
        sum += a[i]; // ...and determine its element-sum

        int arrayCount = 1; // count the sub-arrays with this element-sum
        int currentSum = 0; // sum in the currently traversed sub-array
        for (int j = i + 1; j != a.length; ++j) {
            currentSum += a[j];

            // if sum matches, we found the end of the currently traversed sub-array
            if (currentSum == sum) {
                arrayCount += 1;
                currentSum = 0;
            }
        }

        // tricky part (see below)
        if (currentSum > 0 || currentSum % sum != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        arrayCount += currentSum / sum;
        if (arrayCount > res) {
            res = arrayCount;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Up until the "tricky part", this should be the naive implementation you'd probably come up with on your first attempt. There is no issue with having negative numbers per se. They will simply reduce `currentSum`, requiring later elements to again increase it appropriately until eventually - by collecting enough elements - `currentSum == sum`. At some point (beyond the initialization) `currentSum` may also be `0` or even something negative. This is no problem either. Particularly, `currentSum` being `0` only indicates that we're currently traversing through a sub-array that itself has a leading `0`-sum sub-array.

The only situation a problem occurs is when we have remaining elements at the end of the array, that together did not form a whole sub-array with element-sum `sum` - i. e. `currentSum` is not `0` after the last inner loop iteration. There starts the "tricky part" where we have to distinguish three cases. The remaining elements' sum (i. e. `currentSum`) is

1. positive. However, apparently the remaining elements themselves could not be split in a way that yielded sub-arrays with element-sum `sum` (otherwise that would have happened in the just finished inner `for`-loop already).
2. negative with `currentSum % sum != 0`. Since all elements *up to* the remaining elements in total have a multiple of `sum` as the element-sum, the entire array does *not* have such a multiple as total element-sum.
3. negative with `currentSum % sum == 0`.

Each for their individual reason, 1) and 2) render cases in which we cannot have an appropriate partition with the current value of `sum` *at all*. In 3) however, we have some negative "overhead" that we can perfectly even-out with some (one or more) of the previously found sub-arrays with element-sum `sum` each, in total forming a `0`-sum sub-array. That sub-array can then be simply seen as appended to the sub-array in front of that (again with element-sum `sum`), building a joint sub-array still of size `sum`.

Let's take your second example and look at when we're in outer iteration `i = 0` and have just left the inner `for`-loop. We have `arrayCount = 3` (the three individual `[2]`-arrays), and `currentSum = -2`, now we can join the "remaining elements" (only the `-2`) with the last `[2]` array to form a `0`-sum-array and append that to the second-last `[2]` array. We have in total *lost* one array to the merge that we previously counted in `arrayCount`. This is taken into account by `arrayCount += currentSum / sum;` (note that at this point `currentSum` is non-positive so the division is non-positive and `+=` is actually correctly *decrementing* `arrayCount`). Note that after that line `arrayCount` could even be negative (or `0`) if the remaining elements had a higher negative sum - like `-10` (or `-6`) - but that only tells us, that the whole array's total element-sum had the opposite sign of the current value of `sum` (or is `0`), which again tells us that there is no appropriate partition. In that case however, `arrayCount > res` just fails and we disregard that iteration.

---

If you're particularly attentive, you might have wondered about what happens when in some outer iteration `sum = 0`. This would currently cause an exception but you can easily add a workaround just before the "tricky part":

```
if (sum == 0) {
    if (currentSum == 0 && arrayCount > res) {
        res = arrayCount;
    }
    continue;
}
```

or something equivalent. Indeed, in *that* case, we are in fact *not* able to even-out the negative "overhead" with any number of previous `sum`-sum arrays (since `sum` is `0`), since - just like in case 2) above - `currentSum` is not a multiple of `sum`.

And since we're already thinking of `sum = 0`, what's about `sum < 0`? To also handle that case properly, we only have to change `currentSum > 0` to `currentSum != 0 && ((currentSum > 0) == (sum > 0))`<sup>1</sup> since the rest of the code already is sign-unaware regarding `currentSum` and `sum`. Go figure!

---

<sup>1</sup>: Certainly, at this point we can simplify some logic expressions and `if`-statements when also regarding the `sum = 0` and `sum > 0` case.

Comment: `maxSplitCount([5, 9, 9, -9, -10, -9, 3, -10]) == 6` ?

Comment: @josejuan This is because with this input `sum` will be negative at some point. Please see the last section where I addresses this case (and `sum = 0`). With the updated algorithm, it does yield the correct result `1`.

Comment: You are right @Reizo